# How to Encrypt A Certain Column automatically with ColumnTransformer?

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate

```
@ColumnTransformer(forColumn = "description", read = "pgp_sym_decrypt(description, current_setting('encrypt.key'))", write = "pgp_sym_encrypt(?, current_setting('encrypt.key'))")
@Column(name = "description", length=6000)
@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
private String description;
```

I have this column transform where I encrypt the column before saving to the database.
Sometiems it works but most of the time it shows this error. The database not just this, and it works for other columns. Only on this particular column, it wont work. Do you have ideas? Could this be server related issue? As the application works on the test and local machines

```
column "description" is of type bytea but expression is of type character varying.  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@Lob` annotation, unless the DDL type is `oid`. Other than that, the mapping looks good to me. Share the stack trace of the error and the failing SQL in case this doesn't help.